# Django - working with queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

My models currently look like this:

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, default='')
    url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=255,default='')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Price(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, default='')
    dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, default='')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.price)
```

What I want to be able to do is answer the following question (something that will ultimately become the context of my view):
Show me a list of cars in a particular category that are available at different dealerships, with their prices. The query that I'm using for testing is this:

```
carprice = Price.objects.filter(car__category='1').values('car__name','price','dealer__name').order_by('car__name')
```

The resulting QuerySet looks something like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'car__name': 'Audi Model A', 'price': Decimal('32000.00'), 'dealer__name': 'Dealer A'}, {'car__name': 'Audi Model A', 'price': Decimal('35000.00'), 'dealer__name': 'Dealer B'}, {'car__name': 'Audi Model A', 'price': Decimal('35000.00'), 'dealer__name': 'Dealer C'}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

Question 1: Can the query be modified so that the QuerySet does not repeat the car__name every time but instead groups prices and dealers by car__name? If someone could point me to a good tutorial/documentation on QuerySets, I would be really grateful. I've tried looking at Django's documentation and couldn't really find an answer to this question.

```
- Audi Model A
    - Dealer A 32000.00
    - Dealer B 35000.00
    - Dealer C 35000.00
```

Question 2: With the current query, how can the grouping be done in the view function to achieve the look above?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting this page looking for an answer, here's the best I could come up with:

**Question 1**:
Based on my review of Django documentation and the interaction I had with another Django developer, the answer is (probably) no.

**Question 2**:
The answer is: regroup template tag. [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)